# Returning xml sub elements from attributed elements with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've got the below XML and I'm trying to pull the value of the sub categories depending on the attribute of the parent and put them in a combo box.

The XML

[image]

The problem is that after I run this code (Below) it only returns the first element value (in this case Major). is there anything blatantly obvious that Im missing?

The class

```
public static List<string> GetScalesComboBox()
        {
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load("data/static/Categories.xml");
            var querylist = new List<String>();
            var Subcat = from a in xelement.Elements("Cat")
                         where (string)a.Attribute("id") == "Scales"
                         select a;

            foreach (XElement e in Subcat)
            {
                string Cate = e.Element("Subcat").Value;
                querylist.Add(Cate);
            }
            return querylist;
        }
```

and using it to get into the combobox

```
List<String> ScaleComboList = XMLUtility.GetScalesComboBox();
            for (int i = 0; i < ScaleComboList.Count; i++)
            {
                CMB_SubCategory.AddItem(ScaleComboList[i]);
            }
            CMB_SubCategory.selectedIndex = 0;
            CMB_SubCategory.Enabled = true;
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'll never understand why people go through the trouble of taking a screen grab instead of copying and pasting code.

Comment: First off `Subcat` is actually a collection of the "Cat" elements so that's not a really good name.  Then you use `Element("Subcat")` instead of `Elements("Subcat")` which means you just get the first "Subcat" in the given "Cat" instead of all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop, in the line `string Cate = e.Element("Subcat").Value`, you are selecting *only* the first element. You can try to change the loop's head to
`(XElement e in Subcat.Elements())`, which will iterate through all child elements.
After that, change the loop's body to `querylist.Add(e.Value);`

The full code:

```
foreach (XElement e in Subcat.Elements())
    querylist.Add(e.Value);
```